# pandas merge dataframe based on same value in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have 2 dataframe as below:

```
   student_name student_id   
1  may          0000  
2  june         1111  
3  july         2222 

  member_id member_name school_name
1 A0        april       MIT
2 B0        may         NIT
3 C0        june        LIT
```

i want to join the 2 dataframe in a way to produce result as below.

```
student_name student_id member_id member_name school_name
may          0000       B0        may         NIT
june         1111       C0        june        LIT
```

i am think in sql way where student_name = member_name. 
but i hardly able to do it in pandas.

i have try pandas merge which can base on one same name column.
can you teach me a simple method to make the required results.

thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) and pass the columns to merge on for `left_param` and `right_param` respectively:

```
In [27]:
df.merge(df1, left_on='student_name', right_on='member_name')

Out[27]:
  student_name  student_id member_id member_name school_name
0          may           0        B0         may         NIT
1         june        1111        C0        june         LIT
```

Comment: how to do if i only need to school_name column?
i am google-ing the pandas merge details, but if u can enlighten me abit more. thank you.
student_name student_id school_name

Comment: Just sub-select from the merged df: `merged['student_name','student_id','school_name']`